# How to fetch data from single column stored in array using laravel?

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, laravel

I need to fetch the each and every column individually from the field `array_payout` can anyone solve it

```
$currentMonth_start_Date = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->subMonth(1);
$currentMonth_end_date = Carbon::now()->subMonth()->endOfMonth();

$clients_referral_tree = DB::table('mam_referral_payout')
    ->select('clients.id', 'mam_referral_payout.*')
    //->addSelect(DB::raw('SUM(mam_referral_payout.Final_amount) as referral_amount'))
    ->leftjoin('clients', 'clients.id', '=', 'mam_referral_payout.to_id')
    ->where('clients.id', '=', (Auth::user()->id))
    ->whereBetween('mam_referral_payout.created_at', [$currentMonth_start_Date, $currentMonth_end_date])->get();

$clientTree = [];

foreach ($clients_referral_tree as $tree) {
    $clientThree = $tree;
    $clientTree[] = $clientThree;
}

dd($clientTree);
```

[image: Image Description]

Comment: i have attached the image url to find the execution https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftTg3.png

Comment: Please can you copy and paste the code you have so far.

Comment: I have Added the code on above post

Comment: how about json_decode($clientTree[0]->array_payout) ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF5AA.png how to print all the values in <td> individually

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your Model:

```php
protected $casts = [
    "array_payout" => "object"
];
```

Add an accessor for each attribute in your json like this for example:

```php
public function getTotalAmountAttribute(){
    return optional($this->array_payout)->total_amount;
}
```

You can use them like this:

```php
$clientTree1->total_amount;
```

Comment: i was already using array_payout to store data in array format

Comment: @praveenkumarN, can you explain more please?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF5AA.png i have been using $leads = json_decode($clientTree[0]->array_payout, true); in blade template to get the above image in o/p

Comment: protected $casts = [
    "array_payout" => "array"
]; I have been using this code to store data in array in a single column in database

Comment: i need to display all data in a table i was getting data as an o/p when i use json i have added my json o/p in the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk6EZ.png